How to reduce cost when creating token-2022 when using CLI
I am kind of confused why it cost me .5 sol to create a token-2022 with a transfer hook extension whereas if I use some tools made to create token-2022 with simple extension etc costing only .02 SOL.

That sounds in deed a lot. Could you share the code your are using?

Currently using this example https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/tokens/token-2022/transfer-hook/anchor/TransferHookTransferCost

Looks like creating the mint with the example you posted costs:
Transfer Amount (SOL)   ◎0.00251952
for Allocated Data Size 234 byte(s)
And each token account
Transfer Amount (SOL)   ◎0.00210888
Allocated Data Size 175 byte(s)
If you were paying 0.5 sol maybe that is because that specific example has a transfer fee in wSOL?


Looks like I fucked up my whole code, thanks for the answer though
